# reftex customizing tags for cleveref

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode

Is it possible to customize reftex so that for an equation (when I type "e" after invoking reftex) I get \eqref{eq:blah}  but for anything else (theorem, lemma) I want to get \vref{thm:abc}.
That is, I want to use \eqref for equations, but use \vref (from cleveref) for all other cross references such as  Theorems, Lemmas, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist '(AMSTeX
                           (nil ?h nil "\\vref{%s}")))
```